# Linear Programming: How to implement with multiple constraints?

Tags: linear-programming

I’m trying to solve a linear programing model and need some help. I’m not a programming expert, but I conceptually can draw up the problem and am hoping for some help implementing it.

I’m looking into an asset allocation problem for an investment portfolio from a theoretical perspective, but for simplicity of this post I’m going to use generic terms.

I have a list of 500+ choices that all have an assigned cost and value add. My goal is to maximize the sum of the value add, given a constraint on how much I can spend. These 500 choices are divided into 5 categories and there are restrictions on how many choices I can have from each category.

Category 1 = 1

Category 2 = 1

Category 3 = 2 or 3

Category 4 = 1 or 2

Category 5 = 2

Category 3 + Category 4 = 4

I figure I’ll need to use a binary X variable attached to each choice and 1 means I’m picking that choice and 0 doesn’t so in the end there should be 8 variables that have 1 and the rest have a 0 value that leads to the maximum value add given the constraints on cost each choice has.

I ultimately hope to be able to run and say for example “what is the nth highest value” so instead of getting the maximum value add I can get the second highest value add and so on.

Is this possible and what software/language would be best to do it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify writing everything down, let's assume you had 15 assets, with value added `v_1, v_2, ..., v_15` and costs `c_1, c_2, ..., c_15`. Let's assume assets 1, 2, and 3 are in category 1, assets 4, 5, and 6 are in category 2, assets 7, 8, and 9 are in category 3, assets 10, 11, and 12 are in category 4, and assets 13, 14, and 15 are in category 5. Finally, let's assume a budget B.

We would create binary variables `x_1, x_2, ..., x_15` to indicate whether we bought each asset. Now, the objective function of our integer program is:

```
max v_1*x_1 + v_2*x_2 + ... + v_15*x_15
```

Our budget constraint is:

```
c_1*x_1 + c_2*x_2 + ... + c_15*x_15 <= B
```

Exactly one choice from category 1:

```
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1
```

Exactly one choice from category 2:

```
x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 1
```

Either 2 or 3 choices from category 3:

```
x_7 + x_8 + x_9 >= 2
x_7 + x_8 + x_9 <= 3
```

Either 1 or 2 choices from category 4:

```
x_10 + x_11 + x_12 >= 1
x_10 + x_11 + x_12 <= 2
```

Exactly 2 choices from category 5:

```
x_13 + x_14 + x_15 = 2
```

Exactly 4 choices from categories 3 and 4 combined:

```
x_7 + x_8 + x_9 + x_10 + x_11 + x_12 = 4
```

Finally, you would specify all variables to be binary.

Note that the only adjustment you would need to your problem is to change the variables in each of these constraints to be the variables associated with each of your five categories.

All that remains would be to implement the model. There are a myriad of linear programming packages in all major languages; check out [this survey](http://www.orms-today.org/surveys/LP/LP-survey.html) for details. Since Stack Overflow is not a software recommendation site and you haven't really given any details about your situation (e.g. free vs. non-free solvers or the programming language you're using), I will refrain from suggesting a particular package.